# Eevee Render goes almost all white. Cycles is fine

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Just starting to learn Blender.

I needed an animated camera moving through a cave for the end of a music video. So I bought a cave model.
Am going through beginner tutorials as fast as possible.

But, for now, I've got the camera animation the way I want it.

Here's the problem. When I Render in Cycles, it looks great.
When I switch to Eevee it's washed out.

I'm going to have a render farm do the rendering since it'll take forever to do on my 11 year old Mac Pro.

Basically, I just need some verification that it'll come out alright with the render farm.
I'm assuming they'll use Cycles to render it.

Thanks.

Here's a frame of a cycles and an eevee render:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am guessing that you have a bright world background. Since EEVEE fakes environment lighting and does not cast shadows from it, the world will illuminate the inside of the cave in EEVEE. Cycles does not fake that and thus the world does not illuminate the inside of the cave in cycles except in the entrance.

Comment: I was just looking for how to find the world background. Didn't find that yet, but just for the hell of it I changed the Materials setting from "F Baked Material" to "F Real Material" and it's now displaying correctly.

I see the difference between the baked and real, but now which ever one I choose I'm getting the right render.

Have no clue why, but it's working now.
EDIT.....
Never mind.

I hit Render Animation and it's back to the wrong setting.
What I was looking at when it seemed right was "material  view" not render view.
So I'll try to find the world setting you talked about.

Comment: Aha!
Found the world Background strength. Put it down to zero and it's working now.

Thanks.